# How to properly search for wildcard characters using variables in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, wildcard, string-comparison

When doing string comparison, the `-like` comparator is my usual go-to solution.

But there is one odd thing I cant wrap my head around when using wildcards with variables.

#### String example

This will work...

```
$Test = 'My string'
$Test -like "My*"

True
```

This will mess some things up

```
$Test = '[My string]'
$Test -like "[My*"

WildcardPatternException: The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: [My*

$Test -like '`[My*'
True
```

#### Variable example

But how do I use this with a variable used as search argument?

```
$Test = 'My string'
$Search = 'My'

$Test -like "$Search*"

True
```

This will fail as `[` will be parsed as part of a wildcard construction...

```
$Test = '[My string]'
$Search = '[My'

$Test -like "$Search*"

WildcardPatternException: The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: [My*
```

I need the literal content of $Search to be used instead...

#### Work around

One work around is of course not to use `[` in the search variable

```
$Test = '[My string]'
$Search = 'My'

$Test -like "*$Search*"

True
```

But that will of course catch more strings then `[My`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually thought I tried this...
But I must have missed this solution somehow.

```
$Test = '[My string]'
$Search = '`[My'

$Test -like "$Search*"

True
```

So escaping special characters in the variable declaration **do** work.

```
'`*'
'`\'
'`~'
'`;'
'`('
'`%'
'`?'
'`.'
'`:'
'`@'
'`/'
'``'
```

#### Edit

I found out the actual issue I was having. In my own code, I was actually using a variable to define my search variable.

```
$Test = '[My string]'

$SearchString = 'My'
$Search = "``[$SearchString" #I need to escape the escape character at this point...

$Test -like "$Search*"

True
```

Comment: You can also use `[WildcardPattern]::Escape('[My')`

Comment: The `-match` operator uses regular expressions. More capable than wildcard expressions, it opens a whole new syntax. `'[My string]' -match '\[My'`

Comment: Yes, I try to stay way from regex. It's like witchcraft ;)